# How to create embed code while using JW Player

Tags: iframe, embed, jwplayer

I am using JW-Player in my website and I am generating the embed code against all my videos, but there is something missing because when I embed that code in to my webpage video plays on my PC but it's not playing on Android & iPhone.

I want that my embed code must work on these too.

Comment: We're going to need more than that. Please give us a link to your site. But if you're trying to play FLV's, for example, that won't work on any mobile device, because there's no Flash on a mobile. Convert all videos to MP4.

Answer (score 0):

The player has built in social sharing options.

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1409823-social-sharing-overlay